# Поиск в ini файле

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, ini

я создаю бота, используя discord.js.

Как мне сделать поиск по ini файлу?

Пробую такой код

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ini = require("ini");

const filePath = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.ini, 'utf-8'));
if(filePath.name === args[0])
  return message.channel.send('Данное имя уже занято');
```

ini файл:

```
[id1]
name=test

[id2]
name=file

[id2]
name=safe
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini

Comment: Я не могу найти, укажите мне пожалуйста

Comment: Задача не ясна. Так что общий ответ: npmjs.com/package/ini если тебе нужен модуль, fs.readFile если тебе нужно простое решение для чтения и поиска, [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) если тебе нужно эффективное решение для чтения и поиска

Comment: Извините, я хочу получить что-то в духе:

код:
const fs = require('fs');
const ini = require("ini");

const filePath = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(`file.ini`, 'utf-8'));

if(filePath.name === args[0]) return message.channel.send('Данное имя уже занято');

ini файл:
[id1]
name=test
[id2]
name=file
[id2]
name=safe

Comment: Использовать ini файл как хранилище данных - такая себе идея

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs')
  , ini = require('ini')

const config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./users.ini', 'utf-8'))

console.log(config)
// { id1: { name: 'test' }, id2: { name: 'safe' } }

const name = 'safe'// args[0]
for (const [key, section] of Object.entries(config)) {
  if (section.name === name) {
    throw new Error(`Name «${name}» already exists`)
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/VirtualConfusedSandbox

*Секция с `name=file` у вас некорректная и замещается следующей с тем же именем(id2). Поэтому имя file найдено не будет*

Comment: Можно таким способом искать слова, нетолько в значениях name='one', а ещё в значениях array[]='one' ?

Comment: Почему нет? Смотрите, что находится в config после ini.parse и работайте с ним. Это обычный js объект

Comment: К сожалению, я немного далёк от всего этого, я немного не понимаю как, можно пожалуйста лёгкий пример как это будет примерно выглядеть. Я пробывал, просто section.array, но свойство не работает, как бы не видит, так же пробывал section.array.push тоже не работает

Comment: Для начала посмотрите глазами на то, что вам выводит `console.log(config)`

Comment: выдает примерно это: Array : ["one"]

Comment: Поиграйтесь в [Repl.It](https://repl.it/join/jjbodjvg-arthinbox)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А как мне избежать фильтр по секциям ?

Comment: Если у вас возникают вопросы - не стесняйтесь, [задавайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Этот сайт как раз для этого.

Answer (score 1):

**readline** - модуль, который обеспечивает интерфейс для считывания данных из Readable потока (например process.stdin) на одну строку за один раз.

[readline.createInterface](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options)

```
// @ts-check
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

(async () => {
  const checkName = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];

  const check = await findByName(checkName);

  console.log(`Name "${checkName}" is ${check ? 'exists' : 'not exists'}`);

})();

/**
 * @param {string} checkName 
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
async function findByName(checkName) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '../db.ini'));

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  const searchPattern = `name=${checkName}`;

  let check = false;
  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line.startsWith(searchPattern)) {
      check = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return check;
}
```

db.ini

```
[id1]
name=test

[id2]
name=file

[id2]
name=safe
```